# Typeahead.js - Unable to choose suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I must be an idiot. I am using the [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) plugin. I am trying to use custom templates for suggestions. While my custom templates appear, I cannot use the arrow-keys to actually select an item. If I hover over an item, the selection doesn't get highlighted either. I thought it might be just a styling issue. However, if 3 suggestions appear, and I click the down arrow twice, then enter, my selected option does not appear in the text box. Alternatively, if I choose an option with my mouse, the option does not appear in the box.

What am I doing wrong? Currently, I have the following:

```
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/api/suggests?querytext=%QUERY',
    filter: function(results) {
      return $.map(results.Results, function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion;
      });
    }
});
suggestions.initialize();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
    { minLength: 3 },
    {
      name: 'suggestions',
      source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(data) {
          var str = '';
          if (data.Type === 'Customer') {
            str += '<i class="icon-1"></i>';
          } else if (data.Type === 'Product') {
            str += '<i class="icon-2"></i>';
          }
          str += '<div>' + data.Name + '</div>';
          return str;
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

The suggestions popup. The results come from the following JSON:

```
{
  "Results":[
    {
      "Type":"Customer",
      "Id":5,
      "Name":"Bill",
      "LastUpdated":"01-01-2015"
    },
    {
      "Type":"Customer",
      "Id":135,
      "Name":"Billows",
      "LastUpdated":"01-02-2015",
    },
    {
      "Type":"Product",
      "Id":241,
      "Name":"Bill Check",
      "LastUpdate":"01-04-2015"
    }
  ],
  "TotalResults":3,
  "TotalCustomers":2,
  "TotalProducts":1
}
```

How do I a) Apply a highlight to an item when a use hovers over an item with the mouse or uses the arrow keys to get to it b) Put the select item's `Name` value in the input box when the suggestion is selected?

Thanks!

Comment: could you try setting up a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Please don't use fiddle -- SO has this ability built in these days.

Comment: There is no `valueKey` property anymore it is called now `displayKey` and you should definitely set to your `Name` property. So you need to add this to your typeahead config: `displayKey: 'Name',` otherwise typeahead uses the default value which is `value` so in your case because you don't have a `value` property it does not display anything when selected. This should solve the selection problem but not the hover issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {

    var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
          url: '/api/suggests?querytext=%QUERY',
          filter: function(results) {
            return $.map(results.Results, function(suggestion) {
              return {value:suggestion.Name, suggest:suggestion};
          });
        }
    });
    suggestions.initialize();


    $("#bloodhound .typeahead").typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        hint: true,
        highlight: true
    }, {
        name: 'suggestions',
        displayKey: 'value',
        templates: {
          suggestion: function(data) {
            var str = '';
            if (data.suggest.Type === 'Customer') {
              str += '<i class="icon-1">' + data.suggest.Type + '</i>';
            } else if (data.suggest.Type === 'Product') {
              str += '<i class="icon-2">' + data.suggest.Type + '</i>';
            }
            str += '<div>' + data.value + '</div>';
            return str;
          }
        },
        source: suggestions.ttAdapter()
    });
})
```

```js
$(function () {

    var data = {
  "Results":[
    {
      "Type":"Customer",
      "Id":5,
      "Name":"Bill",
      "LastUpdated":"01-01-2015"
    },
    {
      "Type":"Customer",
      "Id":135,
      "Name":"Billows",
      "LastUpdated":"01-02-2015",
    },
    {
      "Type":"Product",
      "Id":241,
      "Name":"Bill Check",
      "LastUpdate":"01-04-2015"
    }
  ],
  "TotalResults":3,
  "TotalCustomers":2,
  "TotalProducts":1
};

    var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: $.map(data.Results, function(d) {
            return {value:d.Name, suggest:d}
        })
    });
    suggestions.initialize();


    $("#bloodhound .typeahead").typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        hint: true,
        highlight: true
    }, {
        name: 'suggestions',
        displayKey: 'value',
          templates: {
    suggestion: function(data) {
          var str = '';
          if (data.suggest.Type === 'Customer') {
            str += '<i class="icon-1">'+data.suggest.Type+'</i>';
          } else if (data.suggest.Type === 'Product') {
            str += '<i class="icon-2">'+data.suggest.Type+'</i>';
          }
          str += '<div>' + data.value + '</div>';
          return str;

        }
  },
        source: suggestions.ttAdapter()
    });
})
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:"Prociono";
    src: url("../font/Prociono-Regular-webfont.ttf");
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 750px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu, .gist {
    text-align: left;
}
html {
    color: #333333;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.title, .example-name {
    font-family: Prociono;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.title {
    font-size: 64px;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.example {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.example-name {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.demo {
    margin: 50px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
    border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
    color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
    background-color: #0097CF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
    margin: 0;
}
.gist {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.example-twitter-oss .tt-suggestion {
    padding: 8px 20px;
}
.example-twitter-oss .tt-suggestion + .tt-suggestion {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.example-twitter-oss .repo-language {
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
.example-twitter-oss .repo-name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.example-twitter-oss .repo-description {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.example-sports .league-name {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 20px 5px;
    padding: 3px 0;
}
.example-arabic .tt-dropdown-menu {
    text-align: right;
}

[class|=icon] {
    color:orange;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<div id="bloodhound">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Customers and Products" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a valueKey to your function pointing it to name? See SO answer here:

[Typeahead.js does give me suggestions but doesn't select them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008860/typeahead-js-does-give-me-suggestions-but-doesnt-select-them?rq=1)