# How to use local variable objects and templates with TypeaheadJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use Typeahead.js for creating a list of articles available in a support section of a website.  I've been able to get Typeahead.js working using the following:

```
var articles = ['Test','Test 2','Article'];

var posts = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: articles
});

$('#search .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'posts',
    source: posts
});
```

The issue with this is I have no way of passing a url to the results... I'm trying to use an array like this:

```
var articles = [{name: 'test', url: 'http://www.example.com'}];
```

That way I can associate the URL of an article with its name. When I change the dataset to that format, obviously the function no longer works since it can't interpret my data.

Once I get the array working, I was hoping to use Typeaheads template function to output the results like so:

```
<a href="Object Url">Object Name</a>
```

Any idea on how I can fix the function to work with the object array and then apply the template to format the results?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253261/create-customize-type-head-using-jquery-and-bootstrap-typeahead/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for another SO article similar, but this did not come up!