# Typeahead not working with with ajax with response is in key=> value format

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, typeahead.js

Hello there i am using typeahead winch working great when i give response only values but when i bind values with keys then the same will not working.
here is my typeahead code.

```
$('#myInputId').typeahead({
    ajax: {
        url: "{some_url}",
        method: 'post',
        triggerLength: 1  
    },
    onSelect: displayResult
});
```

it works fine when i give ajax response like..

```
["logo","PHP","HTML","Javascript"]
```

but not work with..

```
{"1":"logo","2":"PHP","3":"HTML","4":"Javascript"}
```

any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `.typeahead` expects possible result to be `{"value":"possible result":}` when array of objects returned as `source` ; try using `$.map()` to return `source` as `[{"value":"logo"}, {"value":"PHP"}..]`

Comment: ok i bring the response like `[{id:1,skill:logo},{id:2,skill:PHP},{id:3,skill:HTML},{id:4,skill:Javascript}]` then what to do. can you please be more specific of use $.map.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926875/typeahead-js-unable-to-choose-suggestion , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258673/bootstrap-typeahead-not-showing-suggestion-which-have-the-valuekey-starting-with

Comment: they use Bloodhound but i didn't.

Comment: How is `source` set ?

Comment: it set by ajax call  ` ajax: {
        url: "{some_url}",
        method: 'post',
        triggerLength: 1  
    }` where some-url i my ajax file which return `[{id:1,skill:logo},{id:2,skill:PHP},{id:3,skill:HTML},{id:4,skill:Javascript}]`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347121/update-json-on-every-keyup-for-twitter-typeahead

Comment: that also use of bloodhound :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27349494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return json reponse from your ajax call like following :-

// do your query and any extra login
// $results is array from your query

```
$final = array();
foreach($results as $row)
{
    $final[] = $row['key'];
}

return json_encode($final);
```

It may help you.